# WCF Restful service endpoint in Visual Studio giving 404

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I have been struggling to identify the correct endpoint for a simple webservice created with Visual Studio but I keep getting 404 errors.  I've only done one other web service in C# before and I struggled with the same error before and thought I finally had the syntax figured out.

web.config:

```
 <services>
      <service name="LDAPws.LDAPService" behaviorConfiguration="LDAPServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="LDAPws.LDAPServiceInterface" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
```

webServiceContract.cs:

```
namespace LDAPws
{
[ServiceContract(Name = "LDAPService")]

public interface LDAPServiceInterface
{

    //GET operation
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(GetResourcesFaultContract))]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/echo", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string sayHello();
```

webServiceLib.cs

```
namespace LDAPws
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class LDAPService : LDAPServiceInterface
    {


        public string sayHello()
        {
            return "Hello";

        }
```

URL:

```
http://localhost:8585/ldapws/ldapservice/echo
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing incorrectly.  I'm targeting Dot Net Framework 4.0 and hosting in Visual Studio.  I was thinking that the default URI was namespace.webservicename/parameters, but that isn't working for me.  Adding baseaddress and address in the web.config hasn't seemed to help either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of my problems:

I missed adding global.asax file and adding the service to the project.  I.e.,

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("LDAPws", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(LDAPService)));  
    }
```